# How to remove the empty space between the image composable and the Text composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently facing an issue with my Compose code where there is persistent empty space between the Image and InfoText composables, this appeared when i scaled down the image. I have tried removing the padding modifiers  However, the empty space persists, and I am seeking a solution to eliminate this unwanted spacing and have the composables positioned closer together.

```
@Composable
fun Info(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.android_logo)
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null,
            Modifier
                .scale(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp,)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                //.fillMaxSize()
        )
        //Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(0.000000.dp))
        InfoText(name = stringResource(R.string.name), title = stringResource(R.string.title))
    }
}

@Composable
fun InfoText(
    name: String,
    title: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = name,
            //modifier.padding(horizontal = 32.dp).,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 32.sp,

        )
        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You are scaling down the image. From what I know scaling will occupy full space of image but will scale down image shown. try setting height and width instead of scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several stuff are doing that, I think; try the following:

- Remove the `scale` modifier from the Image composable. Scaling down the image might result in the empty space you're experiencing.
- Remove the `padding(horizontal = 16.dp)` modifier from the Image composable. Padding can introduce extra space between composables.
- Remove the `padding(bottom = 8.dp)` modifier from the Text composable in the InfoText composable. This padding adds space at the bottom, which might contribute to unwanted spacing.